# why foreach loop echo every results

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to get only the exact result of my array in this loop:

```
   <?php

        $color_groups = [
            "green" => array('lightgreen', 'green', 'olive', 'malachite'),
            "blue" => array('blue', 'skyblue', 'cyan', 'iris', 'navyblue', 'zaffre')
        ];

        $selected_color_str = 'cyan';

        foreach ($color_groups as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $color) {
                if (preg_match('/' . $color . '/i', $selected_color_str)) {
                    echo $key;
                } else {
                    echo " not_found ";
                }
            }
        }

        ?>
```

**Result:**

not_found not_found not_found not_found not_found not_found **blue** not_found not_found not_found

- but I want to just show **blue** if exists in that array, if not just echo not_found

Comment: I did not understand the question, cause the result you get is just what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each check you are outputting a not_found message, you need only to do this when you've checked all of the options.

You can also use `in_array()` at each group to check rather than looking through each element.

So....

```
// Store for the group key that matches
$matched_group = '';

foreach ($color_groups as $group => $colour_options) {
    if (in_array($selected_color_str, $colour_options)) {
        $matched_group = $group;
        // You can stop looking once found
        break;
    }
}

if ($matched_group) {
    echo 'Found ' . $matched_group;
} else {
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

Comment: do it in function , please!